# Using VBA on powerpoint objects to copy and paste shape dimensions

Tags: vba, powerpoint

It would be great to have a powerpoint function like there is paste special in excel where there are a bunch of characteristics, and you can choose which ones to copy and paste.

Frequently need to use the same dimensions across slides like:
Same left and top position and same width and sometimes, same length
In case of tables, the height of the rows should be the same, esp of the header row
[optional] same colour

Is it possible to have such a functionality in powerpoint using VBA?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: Maybe this free Add-In might help you: https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~pptlabs/ There you have a Sync-function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at Steve Rindsberg's THOR add-in: http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00002-THOR-The-Hammer.htm It will do the size and position part, I don't think it can set table row heights, though.